# Is there a way to append data to the end of a specific cell and add a value to a specific cell using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Just as the name suggests, I have been using openpyxl to do some data automation stuff and I have been trying to find a way to add data to cells without overriding the current data. I need two different methods of doing this; 1, would be taking an input variable and appending it to the end of a string of data in a sentence format. (ex. Hello world. [appended data]') and then 2 would be taking an input variable (which is a number) and adding it to the number that is currently in the cell (250 + [variable]).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current value of the cell and then add it, subtract it or whatever. For example imagine the cell has 3, and you want to add 5 whatever it is in the cell. You retrieve the 3, and then add the 5, and write the result to the cell.

Comment: so how would I practically do that? Right now, I have the cell value which is a dollar amount and then a variable (which is the amount being added to the cell) the other issue is I have it as a for loop to find the cell I am adding the payment to which looks like this
for cell in column_c:
    if cell.value == clientname:
       ws2.cell(row=cell.row, column=5).value = payment

Comment: Not sure what the issue is with your current code. In the last line you'd just write my_cell.value = my_cell.value + var (remembering to adjust for any possible type incompatibilies with the `+` function). It looks like a general Python question rather than an openpyxl question.